# what is the advantage of using openGLUT programming over X windows programming?

Tags: x11

I understand X windows is a library which is used by other programs in linux environment to create windows. OpenGLUT is another library that uses x-window libraries internally to create windows. What exactly is the advantage of using openGLUT over x-windows?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't really ask five questions in one at Stack overflow. I will answer question number three. Glut is a library which lets you use OpenGL and X windows together easily. They are not alternatives. OpenGL is an API for using 3-D graphics hardware. Almost no one uses raw X windows for anything; it is far too tedious.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill sorry about that. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

It just eases the programming as I understand that direct X11 programming is tedious like assembly programming!